# Installation failed, /target/run - mount point does not exist

Tags: dual-boot, server, system-installation, 20.04, subiquity

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on an old Dell Inspiron 7348 laptop. I created a new ext4 root partition next to the Windows partitions (I want to keep Windows there), but the installer is always failing on a mount command:

```
Stdout: + mount --bind /run /target/run
        mount: /target/run: mount point does not exist.
```

**Full log:**

[image: full log]

Comment: You might find more of the log if you open a shell and look in /var/log/installer. Literally the error means that `/target/run` doesn't exist. `/target` is where you are installing to but I'm not sure what creates `run` in there. Can you also give more details on your partitioning config?

Comment: There is a Windows NTFS partition and an ext4 one for the root filesystem. I'm installing without internet connection btw.

Comment: So you just have one Linux partition? I can only suggest checking out the logs and see what they say. Installing without internet access should work though I have an HTTP proxy running so I haven't personally tried it without any access at all.

Comment: I have this exact same error and have no idea how to solve it, any help is appreciated. I'm installing ubuntu on a HPE ProLiant DL360 G3 server.

Comment: @David I think it's related to Python. Maybe changing the Python version could help. I don't have this laptop right now, so I can't reproduce the issue again.